# Why isn't my regex working with str.contains?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a very simple search string. I am looking for a shop called "Lidl".

My dataframe:

```
  term_location  amount
0          Lidl    2.28
1          Lidl   16.97
2          Lidl    2.28
3          Lidl   16.97
4          Lidl   16.97
5          Lidl   16.97
6          Lidl   16.97
7          Lidl   16.97
8          Lidl   16.97
9          Lidl   16.97
```

Here I am searching for a regex version of Lidl:

```
r = r'\blidl\b'

r = re.compile(r)


df[df.term_location.str.contains(r,re.IGNORECASE,na=False)]
```

This brings back an empty dataframe.

However if I just put the simple string in `str.contains()` it works and I get the the dataframe of Lidls returned:

```
df[df.term_location.str.contains('lidl',case=False,na=False)]
```

I would prefer to be able to use regex, as I have a few more conditions to build into the query.

So what's happening? I can't figure it out.

Practice dataframe for `pd.DataFrame.from_dict()`:

```
{'term_location': {0: 'Lidl',
  1: 'Lidl',
  2: 'Lidl',
  3: 'Lidl',
  4: 'Lidl',
  5: 'Lidl',
  6: 'Lidl',
  7: 'Lidl',
  8: 'Lidl',
  9: 'Lidl'},
 'amount': {0: 2.28,
  1: 16.97,
  2: 2.28,
  3: 16.97,
  4: 16.97,
  5: 16.97,
  6: 16.97,
  7: 16.97,
  8: 16.97,
  9: 16.97}}
```

Comment: Doesn't the first one say *ValueError: cannot process flags argument with a compiled pattern*?

Comment: i think you should compile like `r = re.compile(r,re.IGNORECASE)` , then `df[df.term_location.str.contains(r,na=False)]` should work

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sadly it doesn't at least in 1.0.5, probably because with that argument order it's thinking it's `case=re.IGNORECASE`, so somehow getting coerced to `True` and not causing an issue.

Comment: @anky This does not work either. Returns an empty dataframe. edit: actually it does work.. not sure what happened. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry,I do not get the problem: what do you need? Why not pass a regex as a string literal? `df[df.term_location.str.contains(r'\blidl\b',case=False,na=False)]` works.

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression is not working because you are trying to match the word "lidl" exactly as it is (in lowercase).

You should either change the first character of the word to uppercase:

```py
re.compile(r"\bLidl\b")
```

or use the `re.IGNORECASE` flag in order to match the word regardless its case:

```py
re.compile(r"\blidl\b", re.IGNORECASE)
```

Keep in mind that `\b` tries to match the word in the beginning of the text. For example, "_Lidl" wouldn't match any of the regular expressions above.

Comment: I thought `\b` signifies a word boundary? For example, I want to find "Lidl" by itself. Not "lidlabc".

Comment: @SCool Yes, `\b` is a word boundary.  You may use it in the string pattern, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62960210/11329890).

Answer (score 1):

Use string literal as pattern argument, it will be parsed as a regular expression:

```
df[df.term_location.str.contains(r'\blidl\b',case=False,na=False)]
                                   ^^^^^^^^^
```

The `case=False` will act identically to `re.IGNORECASE`.

Alternatively, use `(?i)`:

```
df[df.term_location.str.contains(r'(?i)\blidl\b',na=False)]
```